# Eclipse - Running maven package with ignoring maven-war-plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I'm using latest Eclipse and Maven,

I have a project with maven-jar-plugin and maven-war-plugin, as below

Obviously `clean install` will create a jar and a war, But can I run command that only create jar skipping war creation (without changing pom)?

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
            <configuration>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                   <phase>package</phase>
                   <goals>
                     <goal>jar</goal>
                   </goals>
                   <configuration>
                     <includes>
                       <include>**/*</include>
                     </includes>                                     
                   </configuration>
                 </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
           <executions>
             <execution>
               <phase>package</phase>
               <goals>
                 <goal>war</goal>
               </goals>             
            <configuration>
                <classifier>wardeploy</classifier>
                <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
                <warName>MyName</warName>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
            </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>

        </plugin>
```

Comment: Have you defined `<packaging>war</packaging>` which does not look like that...which is the wrong way...

Comment: @khmarbaise Can you explain? because I'm running `clean install` and it works for me

Comment: @khmarbaise I thought to accept my answer, but if you have a different answer I will consider it

Comment: First I would suggest to make a choice what you like to create. A jar or a WAR if you made the decision than remove the other configured part from you pom file...and yes you have to change your pom file...apart from that your setup is bad practice cause you are trying to create two things war and jar which is usually done in two separate projects....

Comment: @khmarbaise we are using also build war to add resources that will be taken in a separate build war project that is building multiple jars and their resources

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I succeeded skipping war (creating only jar) using

```
clean install -Dmaven.war.skip
```

Found it in [plugin source](https://github.com/apache/maven-war-plugin/blob/maven-war-plugin-3.2.2/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/plugins/war/WarMojo.java):

> @Parameter( property = "maven.war.skip", defaultValue = "false" )